# Sum Distinct Count Measure from Cube for Drill Down SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, ssrs-2012

I have a report that pulls data Site and then drills down to User for Content Usage for Six Months.  These are separate dimensions in the cube.  I have a DistinctContent Measure that pulls for both Site and User appropriately when I use separate queries but it is at the lowest level which is User.  A sum of DistinctContent at the Site level is not appropriate - it needs to be the DistinctContent for the Site, and then drill down to the DistinctContent for User.  I've tried Lookup but it only looks up for one value.  Multilookup doesn't work either.

Counting the content in a member calculation is too slow.  How do I get the DistinctCount for Site?

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Distinct Content]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        Filter
        (
          [Site].[by Type].[Site].ALLMEMBERS
         ,
          [Measures].[Views] > 0
        )*
        Filter
        (
          [User].[by Type].[User].ALLMEMBERS
         ,
          [Measures].[Views] > 0
        )*
        [Time].[Month Year].[Month Year]
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Content].[by Domain Type Item].[Type].&[3]&[1]&[Art]} ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Cntnt]
);
```

Comment: Have you tried returning the Content in the result set and then doing a distinct count within the tablix?  You can keep everything else in you query the same, but add Content to the rows, this way you can just use a regular group in SSRS of Site > User, then a distinct count of Content for the data.

Comment: I tried that first but unfortunately the dataset becomes so huge that it takes too long to run.

Comment: I can't believe how difficult this is.  It seems like it would be relatively common to have a top level of one dimension unique count, drill down to another dimension unique count.  I have two datasets, both already pulling the values that are correct, Distinct Content by Site (for six months) and Distinct Content by User (for Six Months), I just need to figure out how to combine them, or create a measure calc in MDX that pulls the Distinct Count for Site and Six months and doesn't filter down to user in the query.  It's so easy to do in SQL, I just can't figure out the MDX.

Comment: How many rows do your dinensions have? Have you considered employing the NonEmpty() function just before the crossjoin?

Comment: I have Non Empty before the cross join, but not Nonempty.  I'm using filter instead.  The average amount of rows in the dimensions are

Comment: I'm using filter instead of NonEmpty.  The average amount of active members in the dimensions (active meaning that there is content usage):  65 Sites ,  865 Users, 6 Months.  If I added Content to this, the average consumed content is 12 (per month, per person).  What I'm really trying to do is to get the Distinct Content Consumed per Site and the Distinct Content Consumed per User. It is not a *natural* hierarchy I guess.  There's a many to many aggregation via a bridge table that relates the User to Site.  I have to have filter in the report, so aggregate is not an option.